# Ubuntu 16.04 multiple NIC, bridge - Not getting br0 DNS settings

Tags: networking, server, dns, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

After a updated to Ubuntu 16.04 - which has mostly gone very well - everything works except resolving names from the host.

`Resolv.conf` does not pick up dns-nameservers from interfaces (br0) for some reason.

I run several VM's off multiple Nics. I have two bridges br0 and br1. br0 is the internal network and br1 is external.

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto br0
iface br0 inet static
        address 192.168.0.5
    network 192.168.0.0
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        broadcast 192.168.0.255
        bridge_ports enp5s0
        bridge_stp off
        bridge_fd 0
        bridge_maxwait 0
    metric 0
        gateway 192.168.0.15
    dns-nameservers 192.168.0.4
    dns-search xxxxx.net

auto br1
iface br1 inet static
        address 10.192.23.50
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        broadcast 10.192.23.255
        bridge_ports enp8s0
        bridge_stp off
        bridge_fd 0
        bridge_maxwait 0
    metric 1
```

`resolve.conf` does not have my name server

I do have network manager running
my ip route seems right - default out br0. I think if it would pick up my DNS server all would be right with the world.

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: what happens when you ping the DNS server ? have you tried using dig to query it directly ? what are the error messages you are receiving ?

Comment: Hi thanks - Pinging DNS server with IP 192.168.0.4 is fine. Dig works fine as long as I include the @server_ip.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this as well with upgrade to 16.04 from 14.04.

I looked on launch pad and found an open bug which I think matches:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dnsmasq/+bug/1384394

The final workaround seems to be to remove file:

`/run/resolvconf/interface/NetworkManager`

I cannot confirm the workaround because since finding this thread I have updated with `apt-get upgrade` and rebooted and the problem is absent for me.

That file

`/run/resolvconf/interface/NetworkManager`

is also absent now.

I think that this is the solution (for 16.04) and the workaround for 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution - although not sure it's the right one.

Adding the line: `nameserver 192.168.0.4`

into `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head`

Seems to have done the trick.

Comment: It is a workaround not a solution.